# Why is hg fetch a deprecated extension?

Tags: command-line, version-control, mercurial

Mercurial's [fetch extenson](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FetchExtension) conveniently pulls and merges from a remote repository. Recently, this feature has been deprecated by the developers. They recommend avoiding it and it is on the [unloved features](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UnlovedFeatures) list.

It is useful in many cases to be able to pull and initiate a merge with one command (which hg pull -u doesn't do). I assume there is a reason behind the deprecation but I haven't been able to find one in the [documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FetchExtension) or online. What is the reason behind deprecating it? I'm not looking for opinions, but rather the factual reason behind its deprecation (which might be that the dev team's opinion is that it should not be used).

Comment: The reason I could find is that no core developer is using it. This leads to low maintenance and is treated as a sign of questionable usefulness. See https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2011-September/034116.html